# How to add parameters to existing parameters list?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I get all parameters of a build using -

```
def myparams = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(ParametersAction).getParameters()
```

`myparams` is object of `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` hence if try  to add another parameter to it like  -

```
myparams.add([$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Test', value: "TestValue"])
```

then it fails with error -

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Please guide how to add parameter to existing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

With a trick, I am able to resolve this by converting `UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` to `ArrayList`  and store it in another variable and make use of that variable -

```
def myparams = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(ParametersAction).getParameters()
List<String> paramsList = new ArrayList<String>(myparams.subList(0, myparams.size()))
```